# Unknown field Solr with Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, solr, sitecore

I added a new CalculatedField that return a collection of string.
Then I put it like this in teh Item search class:

```
[IndexField("sessions_dates")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]       
public virtual List<DateTime> SessionsDates { get; set; }
```

Then I declare that in the Solr config file from my solution:

```
 <field patch:after="*[@fieldName='isbucket_text']" fieldName="sessions_dates"    returnType="datetimeCollection" >SiteCore.Utilities.ComputedFields.SessionsDates,SiteCore.Utilities</field>
```

I got this error on the Solr logging page:
[image]

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/{7921a95b-530b-49b4-b6d8-6ffae4503f3a}?lang=en&ver=1] unknown field 'sessionsdates_dtm'
```

It seems that the index field is not added to Solr but I don't know why!
Please can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in the Sitecore Solr schema generation which means the dynamic field has the wrong pattern. You need to replace the line

`<dynamicField name="*_tdtm" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />`

with

`<dynamicField name="*_dtm" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />`

.. then it should match the pattern in the Sitecore Solr config.

Comment: Which config file exactly should I modify plz? there are plenty of config files that holds that line.

Comment: You should modify the `schema.xml` file found in your itemBuckets core inside the Solr application. The dynamicField element should be in there :)